# File.Exists(curFile) Error

Tags: vb.net

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 VB.net.
Every time I try to use `If File.Exists(curfile) = True Then` It comes back with `Error 1   'File' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.` Am I missing an API?

Comment: You're not using VBA, but vb.net  You need `Imports System.IO` in your code module

Comment: I only see System.IO.Compression, System.IO.Compression.FileSystem, and System.IO.Log.

Comment: I apologize, I figured it out, I didn't know it was like Java where I just stick it in the code. I thought it would appear in the framework menu. Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you try `If System.IO.File.Exists(curfile) = True Then`

Answer (score 0):

You need either to import `System.IO` or change code to `If System.IO.File.Exists(curfile) = True Then`.